# Ubuntu 12.04 is stuck at startup after upgrading, now I want to install a new copy of 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 13.10, bootloader

I installed 12.04 as a fresh copy which made GRUB my default bootloader and Windows 7 loader became 6th option in this bootloader.

If I install a fresh copy of 13.10 in the same partition as 12.04 (after formatting that partition), will I be able to access Windows 7 in the new bootloader as 5th or 6th option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,you can access windows 7 in the new bootloader after installing ubuntu 13.10 in the formatted partition.

If not,then boot into ubuntu 13.10,openup the terminal and run the below command to update grub,

```
sudo update-grub
```

After restart you will see both windows and ubuntu option on the grub menu.

Comment: One more thing.. while I install an ubuntu using this method. I have to set mount points for each and every drive. And if I do so, then those drives are shown in the form of folders with the name of the respective mount points. Is there any method by which I can access those drives as drives only (and not as folders).

Comment: After installing ubuntu,your drives will appear on the unity.Clicking anyone of that drive will automatically mounted in /dev/media.

Comment: So is there any need to create the mount points while installing Ubuntu ?

Comment: Actually after installing 12.04, I couldnt find any drives which were shown in unity !

Comment: did you find it on gparted?

Comment: Being a newbie.. I have no idea, what a 'qparted' means ?

Comment: gparted means gparted partition editor which is a software used to resize,create,delete partitions.Boot up the ubuntu live cd and click on try ubuntu after the desktop screen appears press ctrl+alt+t it will open up the terminal.Run this command on the terminal to install gparted `sudo apt-get install gparted`.After installation completed open it.For this you need an internet connection.